# How to egrep variable-Unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix, csh

I’m trying to validate input by using egrep and regex.Here is the line from script (c-shell):

```
echo $1 | egrep '^[0-9]+$'
if ($status == 0) then
set numvar = $1
else
    echo "Invalid input"
    exit 1
endif
```

If I pipe echo to egrep it works, but it also prints the variable on the screen, and this is something I don't need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To simply suppress output you can redirect it to the null device.

```
echo $1 | egrep '^[0-9]+$' >/dev/null
if ($status == 0) then
set numvar = $1
else
    echo "Invalid input"
    exit 1
endif
```

You might also want to consider using the `-c` option to get the count of matches instead of using using the status.

Also, unless you are using `csh`, the status is stored in `$?` not in `$status`

Comment: I used the -c option as you suggested, and I also set new variable to be used in if statement. 
    set temp = `echo $1 | egrep -c '^[0-9]+$'`
    if ($temp != 0) then

Comment: In csh, the exit status is indeed stored in `$status`

Comment: I added a clarification about csh and will add a csh tag as well.

Answer (score 3):

`grep` has a `-q` option that suppresses output

So:

```
egrep -q '^[0-9]+$'
```

Comment: The man page says: "Portable shell scripts should avoid both -q  and -s and should redirect standard and error output to /dev/null instead.  (-s is specified by POSIX.)"

Comment: @Dennis - You are right about the portability issue. Actually both the -s and -q options are specified by POSIX. The -q option acts in the way I use it here, the -s option suppresses error messages. See http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/General-Output-Control.html#General-Output-Control

Comment: portable shell scripts probably won't be written in csh

Answer (score 0):

you can use awk

```
$ echo "1234" | awk '{print $1+0==$1?"ok":"not ok"}'
ok
$ echo "123d4" | awk '{print $1+0==$1?"ok":"not ok"}'
not ok
```

Comment: Thanks but I would prefer the egrep, only because I don't know awk. I will probably give it ago in the future, but as for now I don't have time to learn it.